# Access methods in class contained in another class without referencing the contained class

Tags: c#, class, monogame

I have a `Screen` class which contains the `SpriteBatch` from Monogame. I want to access the `SpriteBatch.Draw()` method, without having to do `Screen.spriteBatch.Draw()`, but instead:

```
screen.Draw(sprite, position, color);
```

I could do this by just defining methods like so:

```
class Screen
{
    public void Draw(Texture2D texture, Rectangle rect, Color color)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rect, color);
    }
    public void Draw(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Color color)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, color);
    }

    .... and so on for every other override of SpriteBatch.Draw
}
```

But this is obviously very long, and I would rather not have to manually type out every override.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: are you sure you have abstracted the functionality at the right level?  You've given the screen the spritebatch, usually this would mean you want the screen to be in charge of using sprintbatch to draw something - like a scene, complex movements, etc - not just express the same functionality that the contained class uses.

Answer (score 0):

Have the Screen class inherit from SpriteBatch, in code it would look like:

```
Screen : SpriteBatch
```